# selecting a element which has a class with jquery hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four div with class name **.s-list**. When the user clicks on any of those divs **.selected** class is applied on the div.

What I am trying to do is while clicking on a button, check all those divs and if any one of them has a class **.selected** submit a form, else if none of the div has a class **.selected** show a error message.

The problem:
It works for the first time, but again if I click the button it shows the error message and submit the form when the div already has the class selected.

```
$("#pp-btn").click(function() {

    $(".s-list").each(function (i) {
         if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')) 
         { 
            $("#p-msg").show(); 
         } 
         else { 

            $("#plans-form").attr('action', $(this).attr('links'));

            $("#p-msg").hide();
         }
        });  
    });
```

I don't want the message to be displayed if any 1 of the div has class 'selected'.

Help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a jQuery selector to check if any `s-list` element has a `selected` class;

```
$('#pp-btn').click(function (e) {

    if ($('.s-list.selected').length == 0) {
        /* No `selected` class on any `s-list` */
        $('#p-msg').show();
    } else {
        /* At least one `s-list` has the additional `selected` class */
        $('#plans-form').attr('action', $('.s-list.selected').attr('links'));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#pp-btn").on('click',function() {
    if($(".s-list.selected").length){ 
       //there are selected items
    } else { 
       //there is none
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check like this :

```
if ($(".s-list.selected").length == 0) { $("#p-msg").show();  }
else {
    $('#plats-form').attr('action', $('.s-list.selected').attr('links'));
    $("#p-msg").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#pp-btn").click(function() {

       var submit = false;

       $(".s-list").each(function (i) {
           if($(this).hasClass('selected')) { 
            submit = true;
           }
        }); 

       if(submit) {
           $("#p-msg").show(); 
       } else {
           $("#plans-form").attr('action', $(this).attr('links'));
           $("#p-msg").hide();
       }
    });
```